# Mbunit and selenium

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, mbunit

Can anyone tell me how get mbunit to run more than one test at a time without it setting up and tearing down after every test?

Currently I'm using selenium for UI testing and need to run the tests consecutively do a login page.

Thanks in advance,
cb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for **FixtureSetUp/FixtureTearDown** attribute [used to be called TestFixtureSetUp], which is called at class level, meaning, it will be set up once for all the tests in one test class.

**Setup/TearDown** attribute is called on Method level.

MbUnit also support test assembly setup and teardown. Here is a [link](http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/639) for this.

```
[assembly: AssemblyCleanUp(typeof(AssemblyCleaner))]
...
public class AssemblyCleaner
{
    [SetUp]
    public static void SetUp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up {0}", typeof(AssemblyCleanUp).Assembly.FullName);
    }
    [TearDown]
    public static void TearDown()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up {0}", typeof(AssemblyCleanUp).Assembly.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks J.W, answered a few other questions I had as well :)